# ASP.NET application how to check the proxy used for request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

I've an application that calls some services through a web-proxy.
I'd like to show the information about the proxy used for requests.
How can I do this?

My code is like the follow:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
log(response.StatusDescription);
// HERE I'd like something like log(request.getProxy()))
reponse.Close();
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy can be configured for the whole application and can be overridden for certain `WebRequest`.
For the application it can be obtained by this code (it looks like it is your case):

```
IWebProxy appProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

For a certain `WebRequest`:

```
IWebProxy requestProxy = request.Proxy;
```

Then you can log the information from that `IWebProxy`:

```
string proxyAddress = appProxy.GetProxy(new Uri(url)).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(proxyaddress);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't understand... `requestProxy.GetProxy(new Uri(url)).ToString()` returns the same url that I've set in the variable `url`. I was expected the proxy address? Isn't?

Comment: It means that the proxy is not configured. Take a look how to configure the proxy in the [app.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/proxy-element-network-settings). If it is configured then it will return proxy address as you expect, else it will return `url` variable value.

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!